# Suggest data structure/synchronization method

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition

I have a data source that generates ~1Million events per second from 15-20 threads.

The event callback handler implements a caching strategy, to record changes to objects from the events (it is guaranteed that updates for individual objects always originate from the same thread)

Every 100ms I want to pause/lock the event handler and publish a snapshot of the latest state of all modified objects.

A mock implementation of what I currently have looks like:

```
private static void OnHandleManyEvents(FeedHandlerSource feedHandlerSource, MyObject myObject, ChangeFlags flags)
    {
        if (objectsWithChangeFlags[myObject.ID] == ChangeFlags.None)
        {
            UpdateStorage updateStorage = feedHandlerSourceToUpdateStorage[(int)feedHandlerSource];

            lock (updateStorage.MyOjectUpdateLock)
            {
                objectsWithChangeFlags[myObject.ID] = objectsWithChangeFlags[myObject.ID] | flags;
                updateStorage.MyUpdateObjects.Add(myObject);
            }
        } else
        objectsWithChangeFlags[myObject.ID] = objectsWithChangeFlags[myObject.ID] | flags;
    }

// runs on separate thread  
private static void MyObjectPump()
    {
            while (true)
            {
                foreach (UpdateStorage updateStorage in feedHandlerSourceToUpdateStorage)
                {
                    lock (updateStorage.MyOjectUpdateLock)
                    {
                        if (updateStorage.MyUpdateObjects.Count == 0)
                            continue;

                        foreach (MyObject myObject in updateStorage.MyUpdateObjects)
                        {
                            // do some stuff

                            objectsWithChangeFlags[myObject.ID] = ChangeFlags.None;
                        }

                        updateStorage.MyUpdateObjects.Clear();
                    }
                }

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
    }
```

The problem with this code, while it shows good performance is a potential race condition.

Specifically, it is possibly for the ChangeFlags to be set to None for an object in the Pump thread while an event callback sets it back to an altered state without locking the resource (in which case the object would never be added to the MyObjectUpdates list and would forever remain stale).

The alternative is to lock on every event callback, which induces too much of a performance hit.

How would you solve this problem?

**--- UPDATE ---**
I believe I solved this problem now by introducing a "CacheItem" that is stored in the objectsWithChangeFlags array that tracks if an object is currently "Enqueued".
I've also tested ConcurrentQueue for enqueuing/dequeuing as Holger suggested below but it shows slightly lower throughput than just using a lock (I'm guessing because the contention rate is not very high and the overhead for a lock without contention is very low)

```
        private class CacheItem
    {
        public ChangeFlags Flags;
        public bool IsEnqueued;
    }

    private static void OnHandleManyEvents(MyObject myObject, ChangeFlags flags)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _countTotalEvents);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _countTotalEventsForInterval);

        CacheItem f = objectsWithChangeFlags[myObject.Id];

        if (!f.IsEnqueued)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _countEnqueue);
            f.Flags = f.Flags | flags;
            f.IsEnqueued = true;

            lock (updateStorage.MyObjectUpdateLock)
                updateStorage.MyObjectUpdates.Add(myObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _countCacheHits);
            f.Flags = f.Flags | flags;
        }
    }

    private static void QuotePump()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (updateStorage.MyObjectUpdateLock)
            {
                foreach (var obj in updateStorage.MyObjectUpdates)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _countDequeue);
                    CacheItem f = objectsWithChangeFlags[obj.Id];

                    f.Flags = ChangeFlags.None;
                    f.IsEnqueued = false;
                }

                updateStorage.MyObjectUpdates.Clear();
            }

            _countQuotePumpRuns++;

            Thread.Sleep(75);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In similiar szenarios (logging thread) I used the following strategy:

The events where enqueued to a ConcurrentQueue. The Snapshot thread looks once a while if the queue is not empty. If not it reads everythink out of it until it is empty, executes the changes and then takes the snapshot. After that it could sleep for a while or check again immediatly if there is something more to process and only if not sleep for a while.

With this approach your events are executed in batches and your snapshot is taken after every batch.

About Caching:

I could imagine a (Concurrent)Dictionary where you lookup the object in the event handler. If its not found, its loaded (or whereever it comes from). AFTER event processing its added (even if it was found already in there). The Snapshot method removes all objects it snapshots from the dictionary BEFORE it snapshots them. Then either the event will be in the snapshot, or the object will still be in the Dictionary after the event.

This should work with your premise that all changes to one object come from the same thread. The Dictionary will only contain the objects that are changed since the last snapshot run.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I haven't tested the performance of this approach yet but how would you implement the "caching" strategy. 80% of the event callbacks I get are on objects that are already appended to the update list - I would like to avoid appending all events to a queue as this would utilize a lot of memory and cause garbage collection (latency is a top concern in this project)

Comment: I'm not sure about the implementation of the ConcurrentQueue. But I read and guess it uses SpinLocks (which are very fast) and that it resizes in blocks (like most collections) instead of allocating each element separately. So in your szenario it would never exceed a maximum length and therefore perhaps never will resize. So perhaps there is no issue. As allways for performance and memory problems "Don't guess, measure!" :-)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with the caching. Are not all the objects that receive the events in memory? If not, do you load them on the first event? And you would like to remove them from memory after the snapshot?

Comment: I could imagine a (Concurrent)Dictionary where you lookup the object in the event handler. If its not found, its loaded. AFTER event processing its added (even if it was found already in there). The Snapshot method removes all objects it snapshots from the dictionary BEFORE it snapshots them. Then either the event will be in the snapshot, or the object will still be in the Dictionary after the event.

Comment: Let me clarify the caching requirement: I have about 1.5Million MyObjects all with an unique ID for which I can receive events. A large % of the time I do get multiple events for the same object before each "pump run". When that is the case, I only want to record changes (via ChangeFlags) to the object to ensure the pump processes the same object only once. The ConcurrentQueue works in lieu of my UpdateStorage lock but performance doesn't differ much - my problem still is how to incorporate caching without impacting performance by much

Answer (score 0):

Could you have two `objectsWithChangeFlags` collections, and switch the reference every 100ms? That way you wouldn't have to lock anything as the pump thread would be working on an "offline" collection.